# In tf.slim, whether I need to add the dependency to the loss

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

In tf.slim, I have used the batch_norm.

My question is: whether I need explicitly to add the dependency to the loss?

I think, the slim knew I have used the batch_norm, whether it has automatically add the dependency to the loss? I am very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need.

Could you follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L229):

Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated. By default the update ops are placed in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`, so they need to be added as a dependency to the `train_op`. For example:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```